# Calling Perl script from Ruby with Ruby varibles

Tags: ruby, perl, shell

I want to include a variable in a Perl script I'm calling from a Ruby script. The following doesn't work. Nothing seems to happen. Not critical that I capture output, but it doesn't work without the `2>&1` either.

The difference in the two scripts is that `--timeoffset #{timeOffset}` is included in the first. In the second `#{timeOffset}` is replaced by `28000`. And the double quotes are not in the second. Of course the double quotes are needed to evaluate a variable, otherwise it's just text going to Perl.

```
perlOutput = "`perl '/Users/gscar/Documents/Ruby/Photo\ handling/lib/gpsPhoto.pl' --dir '/Volumes/Knobby Aperture Two/_Download\ folder/Latest\ Download/' --gpsdir '/Users/gscar/Dropbox/\ GPX\ daily\ logs/2017\ Massaged/' --timeoffset #{timeOffset} --maxtimediff 50000 2>&1` "
```

This does work, simple back-ticked input, no Ruby variables

```
perlOutput = `perl '/Users/gscar/Documents/Ruby/Photo\ handling/lib/gpsPhoto.pl' --dir '/Volumes/Knobby Aperture Two/_Download\ folder/Latest\ Download/' --gpsdir '/Users/gscar/Dropbox/\ GPX\ daily\ logs/2017\ Massaged/' --timeoffset 28800 --maxtimediff 50000`
```

The Perl script works well and am not aware of any Ruby alternatives.

Sorry not broken into lines, but otherwise the backticks get confused.

Comment: Since your Ruby statements are so long, perhaps you could describe the differences for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, as [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656498/479863) points out, that you have the wrong quotes. However, there is a much better way to approach this sort of things that avoids all the quoting and escaping and shell problems completely and that way is to use [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) from the standard library. Something like:

```
perlOutput, _ = Open3.capture2(
  'perl',
  '/Users/gscar/Documents/Ruby/Photo handling/lib/gpsPhoto.pl',
  '--dir',
  '/Volumes/Knobby Aperture Two/_Download folder/Latest Download/',
  '--gpsdir',
  '/Users/gscar/Dropbox/ GPX daily logs/2017 Massaged/',
  '--timeoffset',
  timeOffset.to_s,
  '--maxtimediff',
  50000.to_s
)
```

That will give you the output in `perlOutput` and the process's exist status in `_` (you can also say `perlOutput, = ...` but I find the explicit throw-away `_` clearer to read). No shell involved so no extra escaping needed.

If you want `stderr` too, then use [`Open3.capture3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) rather than appending `2>&1` to a shell command to commingle `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `perlOutput, =...`. Alternatively, `perlOutput,* = ...` or `perlOutput = Open3.capture2(...).first`.

Comment: @Borodin: But there is `Open3.capture3` (or `Open3.popen3`, `Open3.popen2e`, or even `Open3.capture2e`) if you're also interested in what `stderr` has to say. And you rarely really want `stdout` and `stderr` mashed into one pile except as a convenience (really a false laziness IMO when there are better options available). I do miss the quality of documentation in the Perl world.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm aware of that, but I think you should be explaining it to the OP instead of to me. It's far from obvious that `Open3` won't handle a final `2>&1` parameter as one may expect it to, and I think it should be addressed in your answer since it's part of the statement that the OP says he wants to get working. A good reason for merging the stdout and stderr streams is a rough and ready way to get an idea of the relative timings of the output. Buffering must be disabled for it to work, but it is simpler than timestamping everything and using an app to merge the two logs.

Comment: @muistooshort: I am reminded of the excellence of Perl's language and CPAN documentation every time I step out of my Perl box. Sadly, I can see Ruby becoming obsolescent just because of this and its poor benchmark results. Perl continues to be fast, and Python doesn't upset programmers in the way that Perl does, despite Perl being a more extraordinary language than most people realise.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many quotation marks. It is the outermost quotes that designate the operation to be performed, so an assignment like

```
perlOutput = "`...`"
```

won't treat the backticks as anything special; they will simply be included in the string

However, backticks or `%q{}` *will* interpolate variables, just as double quotes do, so you want simply

```
perlOutput = `perl ... --timeoffset #{timeOffset} ...`
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I got into that thinking. But after I wrote the last sentence of the second paragraph in the edit, I got to thinking maybe it wasn't true. And it works. I guess I'm used to the using #{} inside double quotes in a put that I got locked into that thinking. Of course, I barely know what I'm doing. Also explains why the question never came up in searches. Duh

Comment: If this were Perl then I would say that you should study the documentation. Unfortunately, Ruby's documentation in the western world consists of a collection of unofficial third-party documents and paid-for books. I can't see it documented anywhere that backticks interpolate blocks in the same way as double quotes, but that's what they do. You should remember that single, double, and backticks are generalised as `%q//`, `%Q//` and `%x//` which allow you to use whatever delimiters you wish so as to avoid unnecessary escaping.

Comment: I would also say that, with a long system command like this you should build a variable, say `cmd`, out of the concatenation of a number of double-quoted strings, corresponding to the executable and each of its parameters. That would let you put each of them on a separate line, so that your code remains readable, and then all you need is `perlOutput = %x/#{cmd}/` to commit.

Comment: `backticks interpolate blocks in the same way as double quotes`. I wrestled with this when I first wrote this script years ago, but just hard coded it, but now I really need the variable, so glad it's finally done right (and simply). @mu is to short and Borodin: Thank you. Worth knowing. All those folder and file locations are variables and when I put them in #{}, the code is pretty clean, but if I there were more variables your approach would be helpful.